# React Props not populated

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, google-map-react

Trying to learn React and following this tutorial:https://youtu.be/GDa8kZLNhJ4?t=3547

There you have a App.js component that makes Travel Advisor API call that populates the data object:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { CssBaseline, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import { getPlacesData } from "./api";
import Header from "./components/Header/Header";
import List from "./components/List/List";
import Map from "./components/Map/Map";
import { PlaceSharp } from "@material-ui/icons";

const App = () => {
  const [places, setPlaces] = useState([]);
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState({});
  const [bounds, setBounds] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPlacesData().then((data) => {
    console.log(data) // data is there
      setPlaces(data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Header />
      <Grid container spacing={3} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
          <List />
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12} md={8}>
          <Map
            setCoordinates={setCoordinates}
            setBounds={setBounds}
            coordinates={coordinates}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The following props are passed to Map component:

```
         <Map
            setCoordinates={setCoordinates}
            setBounds={setBounds}
            coordinates={coordinates}
          />
```

In Map component it gets passed to GoogleMapReact component:

```
import React from 'react'
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react'
import {Paper, Typography, useMediaQuery} from '@material-ui/core'
import  LocationOnOutlinedIcon  from '@material-ui/icons/LocationOnOutlined'
import Rating from "@material-ui/lab"

import useStyles from './styles'

const Map = ({setCoordinates, setBounds, coordinates}) => {

  const classes = useStyles()
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery('(min-width: 600px)')
  
  //console.log(coordinates)
  //const coordinates= {lat: 0, lng: 0}
  
  return (
    <div className={classes.mapContainer}>
        <GoogleMapReact
            bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}}
            defaultCenter ={coordinates}
            center = {coordinates}
            defaultZoom = {14}
            margin = {[50, 50, 50, 50]}
            options = {''}
            onChange = {(e) => {
              console.log(e) // this is empty but it should have data
              setCoordinates({lat: e.center.lat, lng: e.center.lng});
            
            }}
          
            onChildClick = {''}
        >

        </GoogleMapReact>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Map
```

For some reason coordinates prop is not populated in onChange as seen in the video.
I double check the code and cannot find what is stopping it from getting the data.

The API call returns a bunch of restaurants like this:

[image]

So it is fetching the data. Only props {coordinates} not getting filled.
Can you see where can be the issue?

Comment: Sorry, what props are not "populated? How are you verifying/validating this? Is `GoogleMapReact` component's `onChange` callback handler called? What is the value there? Is this where the issue is? What value are you expecting to see there?

Answer (score 1):

There are two pieces of state that handle some state. Those are `places` and `coordinates`. Once the `App` component is loaded, it tries to fetch `places` and update its state, triggering a re rendering. So far, so good.

The `Map` Component receives as prop the value of `coordinates`. `coordinates` never changes in the flow of the snippet that you posted. Maybe you want to fetch some `coordinates` from another endpoint? Or maybe from the `places` data, map through it and set a new state?. Same applies for `bounds`.

What it looks like it is missing is a call to `setCoordinates` and `setBounds` with the new values.